# Why my django urls gets some bad garbage value

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls

When I call http://127.0.0.1:8000 to call my homepage,

I'm automatically redirected to some bad random URL like

http://127.0.0.1:8000/ADwx or

http://127.0.0.1:8000/GRpc

**dashboard urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request,'index/index.html')

def dashboard(request):
   user = request.user
   return render(request,'dashboard.html',{'user':user})
```

**main urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'', include('dashboard.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Your shown code does not explain the observed behavior.

Comment: whenever i hit http://127.0.0.1:8000 it just call something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/FWds this .its so weird @klaus

Comment: Do those random urls actually exist in your urls.py somewhere?

Comment: Is your request authenticated? What's in your template? Any fancy middleware activated?

Comment: no not at all @Sayse

Comment: Do you have main urls.py file in project directory? Can you show it?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner i have edited the question check it

Comment: Can you include any dashboard urls that appear above the home url?

Comment: show your dashboard.urls

Comment: the above url is in dashboards urls.py url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')

Comment: Yes, but are there any other urls above it?

Comment: i have updated the question please check it @Sayse

Comment: Can you add dashbord view also?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner i have added the dashboard view its not full but some highlights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use an regular expression. Thats why you get an bad garbage value.

```
url(r'', include('dashboard.urls'))
```

Where should the url point to ? Use an regular expression like

```
url(r'^', include('dashboard.urls'))
```

to make `url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),` your startpage at [http:/127.0.0.1:8000](http://127.0.0.1:8000)

Based on the comment I think you want that.

**dashboard urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

**main urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls'))
  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: i want to point url like http:/127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard @Aaron